# Encrypt section in web.xml

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, rsa, web.xml

In asp.net there is a tool called aspnet_regiis to encrypt section in web.config.

How can I encrypt web.xml in java using RSA like in ASP?

Thank you

Comment: check this article: http://www.jdev.it/encrypting-passwords-in-tomcat/

Comment: How to do it if I want to encrypt context-param section?
Because after I read the article, its only give explaination about how to encrypt jdbc connection